# how to link Youtube video in Lightbox v2.10.0

Tags: lightbox2

I am using Lightbox v2.10.0 by Lokesh Dhakar in Bootstrap 4, instead of image want to play Youtube video in the modal window, please help me how to do it.

here is what I tried, but i am unable to play Youtube link

```
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
          <img src="img/portfolio/app1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-info">
            <h4><a href="#">App 1</a></h4>
            <p>App</p>
            <div>
              <a rel="iframeLink" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_n3b0rcDEIk" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="App 1" class="link-preview" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What exactly does "unable" mean? An error message?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you like it to autoplay when the modal is triggered?

Comment: Yes I want youtube video to be autoplay and currently I am able to see only preloader with modal window from the above posted code

Answer (score 1):

Lightbox2 does not support videos.

Your best bet is to use an alternative 'lightbox' library that has video support. You could also modify Lightbox2 to have video support, using existing work as a starting point (https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/pull/564), but this would be substantially more challenging.

Comment: No problem! Please mark the answer correct if you think it answers your questions appropriately. If not, let me know if there is anything else I can clarify.